# File deletion when cloning a model that contains an ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

When I save() a model that contains an ImageField, the post_save signal of the model base deletes the file that was previously associated with the ImageField which is fair enough because the file has changed to a new value.

However, if I've cloned the model, i.e. loaded an object from the db, set it's pk to None, set it's ImageField to a new value and then done a save(), I don't want it to delete the original file because it's still in use by the object that was cloned.

```
item = Item.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
item.pk = None
item.thumbnail = <new image>
item.save()                 #<--causes the original Item's thumbnail file to be deleted
```

This feels like its such a normal procedure that there should be a pattern for doing it without overriding signals but I'm damned if I can see it. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

To add some detail of the core processing, `django.db.models.base` method save_base fires a post_save signal

```
post_save.send(
    sender=origin, instance=self, created=(not updated),
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
)
```

Which ends up calling `django_cleanup.handlers` delete_old_post_save method

```
def delete_old_post_save(sender, instance, raw, created, update_fields, using,
                         **kwargs):
    '''Post_save on all models with file fields, deletes old files'''
    if raw or created:
        return

    for field_name, new_file in cache.fields_for_model_instance(instance):
        if update_fields is None or field_name in update_fields:
            old_file = cache.get_field_attr(instance, field_name)
            if old_file != new_file:
                delete_file(instance, field_name, old_file, using)

    # reset cache
    cache.make_cleanup_cache(instance)
```

Comment: Can you share your signal handler that deletes the previous image?

Comment: It's not mine. This is the standard django handler. I've added the relevant code above.

Comment: I gave up looking for a clean answer and just wrote a clone method in the model in the end